# How to give multiple class to single html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created one IMS system. In that, on order page, I have to validate product quantity before generating the order. So for that, I have used jquery selector to compare two values unless the value of the second field will be less than or equal to the first field submit button will be enabled and whenever values go above it button will be disabled. (the first field is stock available and second field is stock given at the time of creating order). but this code is working for an only first product when I enter second product validation is not working. How can i put this code in the loop and I can check every product in an order. An id of a row is automatic incrementing while adding the new product. Below is my code

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
   </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="aqty[]" id="aqty_1" class="form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)"></td>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#qty_value_1,#aqty_1').on('keyup', function() {
                  var btn = $('button:contains("Submit")');
                  if (parseFloat($('#qty_value_1').val()) >= parseFloat($('#aqty_1').val())) {
                      btn.prop('disabled', false);
                  } else {
                      btn.prop('disabled', true);
                  }
              })
</script>
```

My main intention is to check every product quantity before generating the order

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working

Comment: <td> <div class="qtys"> <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off"> <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"> </div> </td> i have tried this but it is not working

Comment: ok how can I use multiple class if u have the example please give here

Comment: <td>
                             <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="qtys form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                             <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="qtys form-control" autocomplete="off">
                         </td> you mean to say like this?

Comment: It seems some messed logic in your code. First note - you try to handle an event `keyup` for hidden input with `id="qty_value_1"`. Why? Second - for `id="aqty_1"` you call inline `getTotal(1)` and then call handler `.on('keyup'...` in the script. Please explain that and answer will come

Comment: is there the only button for all products or different buttons for different table rows?

Comment: single button for all product and getTotal is the function written to calculate a price of a product (qty*rate)

Answer (score 1):

> you can use multiple classes in html one div or ...

```
<div class="container classname classname classname">

</div>
```

Comment: <td>
                             <div class="qtys">
                             <input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
                             <input type="hidden" name="qty_value[]" id="qty_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                             </div>
                         </td>
                         <td><div class="aqtys"><input type="text" name="aqty[]" id="aqty_1" class="form-control" required onkeyup="getTotal(1)"></div></td>

Comment: I want exactly like this

Answer (score 0):

you need to use *CSS attribute selector*. it uses square brackets. For your case you need to select `id`-s that begin with *aqty_*, thus you have to define selector as `[id^="aqty_"]`

Your script may look as follow

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var btn = $('button:contains("Submit")');
  $('[id^="aqty_"]').on('keyup', function() {
          var qty_val = $(this).closest('tr').find('[id^="qty_value_"]');
          if (parseFloat(qty_val.val()) >= parseFloat($(this).val())) {
              $(this).removeClass("warn");
          } else {
                $(this).addClass("warn");
          }
     btn.prop('disabled', $('.warn').length);
  });
</script>
```

Since you have several goods to fill order you have to concern about enabling of button only when all quantities of order don't exceed store values. So the good way is to define class i.e. `.warn` which signs wrong field value.
Last step of script has to be to check in a length of array of elements with class `.warn`. If this length is more than zero, then some value exceeds its limit, else all inputs are good and submit button becomes enabled.

Look at link how it works: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yyt3tkek/)

Comment: it is only validating first product quantity in bill and if the second product quantity is greater than stock than also i am able to generate order which i don't want.

Comment: so clarify condition for IF statement. just describe a logic then put it in the code

Comment: Why class is not working in my code(class="qtys form-control"), if condition already I have put  if (parseFloat($('.qtys').val()) >= parseFloat($('.aqtys').val())) {
                      btn.prop('disabled', false);
                  } else {
                      btn.prop('disabled', true);
                  }